Alternative to now read-only mesh.loops[loop_index].normal on Blender 4.1 for game objects importer add-on
EDIT: the original post assumed that this code was dealing with the bmesh API, out of a confusing naming scheme, which was incorrect. The text and sample code have been corrected.
I'm dealing with a 3D game asset importer add-on. Blender 4.1's mesh deprecations broke the way this add-on assigns the original asset's normals data to a new Blender mesh object, and I'm not knowledgeable enough to solve it.
Basically, the original code used mesh.loops[loop_index].normal to temporarily store normals in the mesh, so that if a mesh.validate() step deleted any geometry, such geometry's normals would be gone while the rest maintained their order for free. Once past the validation, it did read that temporary data and did the actual normals assignation.
This is the block of code where things happened, partially de-indented for legibility:
# game_mesh_data is an object with data parsed from a game object file.


# Create blank Blender mesh with the name of the game mesh object.
blender_mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(game_mesh_data.name)

# Fill it with verts from the game mesh object.
blender_mesh.from_pydata([vert.position for vert in game_mesh_data.vertex_buffer.values()],
                  [],
                  [index for index in game_mesh_data.indices_buffer.values()])


                
# We store temporary normals in loops, since validate() may alter final mesh.
# We can only set custom loop normals AFTER calling it.

blender_mesh.create_normals_split()  # DEPRECATED IN BLENDER 4.1.

for j, polygon in enumerate(blender_mesh.polygons):
    loop_indices = polygon.loop_indices

    for k, loop_index in enumerate(loop_indices):
        v = game_mesh_data.vertex_buffer[game_mesh_data.indices_buffer[j][k]]
        
        # We apply the normals to each loop directly.
        blender_mesh.loops[loop_index].normal = [v.normals.x, v.normals.y, v.normals.z]
        # DEPRECATED IN BLENDER 4.1 where blender_mesh.loops[loop_index].normal is read-only.
        # We need an alternative means to store the normal data in a per-loop basis).

        
# This is the step that might alter the mesh.
blender_mesh.validate(clean_customdata=False)

# Mesh Normals

# Here the Normals are read from the blender_mesh data, with any alterations accounted for.
custom_loop_normals = [0.0] * (len(blender_mesh.loops) * 3)
blender_mesh.loops.foreach_get("normal", custom_loop_normals)

# And here they are set in their definitive form.
blender_mesh.polygons.foreach_set("use_smooth", [True] * len(blender_mesh.polygons))
blender_mesh.normals_split_custom_set(tuple(zip(*(iter(custom_loop_normals),) * 3)))

blender_mesh.use_auto_smooth = True  # DEPRECATED IN BLENDER 4.1: use Smooth Angle Modifier instead.


From 4.1 onwards, mesh.loops[loop_index].normal is read-only, so, I need another way to do the same, which escapes me.
To progress in some form, I've been trying alternatives in 3.6 and 4.0, to see if I can get the same results previous to the mesh.use_auto_smooth() step or its Modifier alternative, as a way to validate it, to no avail.
(I've tried accumulating the normals data in a list by the order determined by the loop, and using mesh.loops[loop_index].normal to assign them before mesh.validate(), and I'm getting something close, but still there are faint discontinuities, showing up as sharp-like, that the original approach solved, and I can see in the resulting objects' normals data slight differences between both)

The FBX importer just uses a temp custom attribute instead: https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/06b25fee0e256184712bee39175ffc211a861da9/scripts/addons_core/io_scene_fbx/import_fbx.py#L1904-L1930

Following your clue, I redid that code to use an arbitrarily named custom attribute. It it didn't solve the issue by itself but led me to learn why: the original normals data wasn't normalized. If I pre-normalize it, it works and the mesh shows no discontinuities. That normalization happened "automagically" in the older technique by using mesh.loops[loop_index].normal to store it. It doesn't happen if using custom attributes. normals_split_custom_set() doesn't seem to do it either. I'm trying to find such a shortcut to save cycles calculating it when importing massive worlds.

Yes, normals_split_custom_set misbehaves badly if the normals are not unit length. You might be able to normalize them quickly with numpy.

As the original asset's parsed data was using the mathutils' Vector type for the normals, I can use the normalize() (acts on the original vector) or the normalized() (returns a normalized copy of the vector) methods. They don't seem to impose much of a time penalty, but still I have to do some tests.

This is odd. The custom attribute data for the temp normals aside, I also create a layer of UV data, which is filled during the same loop as the one filling the custom one.
In some cases, I have to create three layers of UV data instead of a single one (it's to support some animated UV materials), though. If I create the custom attribute layer before I create the additional UV layers, its initial elements (as many 0,0,0 vectors as the mesh' loop indices) completely disappear. I'm having to create it after the UV ones to keep that from happening.
